# Pytest-Django: Uncaught Exception is unfortunately hidden

Tags: pytest, pytest-django

I use pytest-django and the uncaught exception is unfortunately hidden

```
@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_foo(client):
    url = reverse('foo')
    response = client.get(url)
    assert response.status_code == 200
```

I get:

```
E       assert 500 == 200
Assertion failed
```

How can I configure pytest to show the real exception (and not the http 500 response)?

Answer (score 1):

Since `pytest` uses `assert` statements for its tests we can take advantage of the extended form of the `assert` statement as shown [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-assert-statement).

In your case it would look like:

```
@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_foo(client):
    url = reverse('foo')
    response = client.get(url)
    assert response.status_code == 200, response.exception_reason
```

The syntax for retrieving the `Exception` in your case might be slightly different but hopefully you understand what needs to be changed.

Comment: I guess "exception_reason" is a string. I would like to see the whole beautiful stacktrace of the original uncaught exception.

Comment: if you want more information than an extended assertion can provide, then you might be interested in using this [hook](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/reference.html#pytest.hookspec.pytest_assertrepr_compare)